# how to revert lower_case_table_names=1 to lower_case_table_names=0 (default) in ubuntu18

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

I made some changes in my environment in my.cnf of mysql server. one of those change was setting `lower_case_table_names=1` and restarted mysql server.

My application is now throwing error *"Table 'db_name.table_name' doesn't exist"* for one of the table where table name was in camel-case.

I tried to revert the change in config file and restart mysql server but issue still persist.

When I run `show global variables like "lower%";` below is the response -

```
mysql> show global variables like "lower%";

+------------------------+-------+

| Variable_name          | Value |

+------------------------+-------+

| lower_case_file_system | OFF   |

| lower_case_table_names | 1     |

+------------------------+-------+

2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Please help if there is a way to reset the value of lower_case_table_names variable to it's default or if there is a way to retrieve the data of this particular table.

Answer (score 0):

In your linux (ubuntu) enviroment you should find the my.cnf

```
/etc/mysql/my.cnf

edit the  lower_case_table_names to the value you need  then restart  your db 

[mysqld]
#
# * Basic Settings
#
lower_case_table_names=1
```

Comment: This doesn't work. Even after changing config file and restart

Comment: have set the valur for 0  or for 2  ??

Comment: I have set it to 0 now, this is default for Unix.

Comment: check if you have also a sql.ini  file and check for the content

Comment: This file is not present in config folders

Comment: which version of mysql your are using

Comment: MySql version is 5.7.30

Comment: for 8.0  needs a reinit  ..but for 5.7 should not ..  have your tried  to  restar the server and check for the value in use ??

Comment: Yes, value in config is 0 but value in use is 1